# jQuery - draggable and resizeable

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a page that allows people to create a custom we page based on a pre-built page (tempalte if you would)

I have a page built as a start that the customer can then customize the text areas, images, videos etc.

Here is the page that i call the "template"

```
<div id="templateContainer">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var hexDigits = new Array
            ("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"); 

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var editing = false;
        $('.dragThis').each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).attr('data-content-type') == 'text') {
                $(this)
                    .resizable()
                    .css('color', $(this).attr('data-color-default'));
            }
            $(this)
                .bind('dblclick', function () {
                if (editing) return;
                $('#area').val($(this).attr('id'));
                if ($(this).attr('data-content-type') == 'text') {
                    editIT($(this));
                } else if ($(this).attr('data-content-type') == 'image') {
                    changeImage($(this));
                } else if ($(this).attr('data-content-type') == 'video-image') {
                    changeVideoImage($(this));
                }
            }).bind('click', function () {
                $('#area').val($(this).attr('id'));
                var styles = $(this).attr('style').split(';');
                $.each(styles, function (i) {
                    var style = this.split(':');
                    var style0 = $.trim(style[0]);
                    var style1 = $.trim(style[1]);
                    alert(style1);
                    if (style0 == 'font-size') {
                        $('#controls #font-size option[value="' + style1 + '"]').attr('selected', true);
                    } else if (style0 == 'color') {
                        $('#controls #color option[value="' + rgb2hex(style1) + '"]').attr('selected', true);
                    } else if (style0 == 'text-align') {
                        $('#controls #text-align option[value="' + style1 + '"]').attr('selected', true);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
    function editIT(what) {
        editing = true;
        what = what.find("#edit");
        what.html('<textarea id="text_' + what.attr('id') + '" style="width:' + what.css('width') + ';height:' + what.css('height') + ';">' + what.html() + '</textarea>');
        $('#text_' + what.attr('id')).focus();
        $('#text_' + what.attr('id')).blur(function () {
            editing = false;
            var newText = $(this).val().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, "<br />");
            what.html(newText);
        });
    }

    //Function to convert hex format to a rgb color
    function rgb2hex(rgb) {
        rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
        return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
    }

    function hex(x) {
        return isNaN(x) ? "00" : hexDigits[(x - x % 16) / 16] + hexDigits[x % 16];
    }

    function changeImage(what){
        jPrompt('Using the "Image Library" on the left you must first find the image in there and then make any transformation you want to the imate. Once you are happy with yout final image, copy the URL at the bottom of the transformation screen and paste it here:',what.children().attr('src'),'Update Image', function(e) {
            if(e && e != ''){
                what.children().attr('src', e);
                what.css('width', 'auto');
                what.css('height', 'auto');
                what.children().removeAttr('width');
                what.children().removeAttr('height');
            } else {
                if(!e && e == ''){
                    jAlert('Leaving this field blank will keep the default image..', 'Image');
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }       

        });

    }

    function changeVideoImage(what){

        $('#changeVideoOrImageSection #newItemURL').val('');
        $('#changeVideoOrImageSection').fadeIn(200);

    }
    </script>
    <div id="startDragging" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:1014px; height:1144px;background-color:#fff;">
        <div id="area_1" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:33px; height:213px;background:url(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/tpl/landing_page_templates/Full_Page_Template/images/Landing_Template2_01.png) top left no-repeat;"></div>
        <div id="area_2" style="position:absolute; left:983px; top:0px; width:31px; height:1144px;"> <img id="Landing_Template2_03" src="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/tpl/landing_page_templates/Full_Page_Template/images/Landing_Template2_03.png" width="31" height="1144" alt=""> </div>
        <div id="area_3" class="dragThis" style="position: absolute; left: 43px; top: 5px; width: auto; height: auto; overflow:hidden;" data-color-default="#000" data-font-default="Verdana" data-content-type="text"><div id="edit"><h1>Business Name</h1>123 Right Here Way<br>Tampa, FL 33607<br>info@yoursite.com<br>(813) 888-8888</div></div>
        <div id="area_4" class="dragThis" style="position:absolute; left:717px; top:10px; width:236px; height:198px;" data-content-type="image"> <img id="Landing_Template2_06" src="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/tpl/landing_page_templates/Full_Page_Template/images/Landing_Template2_06.png" width="236" height="198" alt=""> </div>
        <div id="area_5" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:213px; width:33px; height:61px;"> <img id="Landing_Template2_07" src="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/tpl/landing_page_templates/Full_Page_Template/images/Landing_Template2_07.png" width="33" height="61" alt=""> </div>
        <div id="area_6" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:274px; width:32px; height:870px;"> <img id="Landing_Template2_09" src="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/tpl/landing_page_templates/Full_Page_Template/images/Landing_Template2_09.png" width="32" height="870" alt=""> </div>
        <div id="contentBG" style="background-color:#005b7f; position: relative; left:32px; top:213px;height:471px;width:951px">
            <div id="area_7" class="dragThis" style="position: absolute; left: 203px; top: 2px; width: auto; height: auto; text-align: center; font-size: 40px; overflow:hidden;" data-color-default="#FFF" data-font-default="Verdana" data-content-type="text"><div id="edit">This is your Primary Heading</div></div>
            <div id="area_8" class="dragThis" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 49px; width: auto; height: auto; text-align: center; font-size: 18px; overflow:hidden;" data-color-default="#FFF" data-font-default="Verdana" data-content-type="text"><div id="edit">Text Block #1 Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi</div></div>
            <div id="area_9" class="dragThis" style="position:absolute; left:562px; top:163px; width:385px; height:303px;" data-content-type="video-image"> <img id="Landing_Template2_12" src="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/tpl/landing_page_templates/Full_Page_Template/images/Landing_Template2_12.png" width="385" height="303" alt=""> </div>
            <div id="area_10" class="dragThis" style="position: absolute; left: 5px; top: 185px; width: auto; height: auto; text-align: left; font-size: 40px; overflow:hidden;" data-color-default="#e2e2e2" data-font-default="Verdana" data-content-type="text"><div id="edit">Heading #2</div></div>
            <div id="area_11" class="dragThis" style="position: absolute; left: 6px; top: 218px; width: auto; height: auto; text-align: left; font-size: 18px; overflow:hidden;" data-color-default="#FFF" data-font-default="Verdana" data-content-type="text"><div id="edit"><ul><li>Text block #2. Quis que tincidunt lectus vel enim</li><li>Donec cursus egestas adipiscing.</li><li>Vivamus aliquam erat non massa ullamcorper</li></ul><p>Quam erat non massa ullamcorper, vel pulvinar nibh lobortis.<br>Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.<br>Maecenas augue lorem, aliquam sit amet faucibus vel, gravida<br>fringilla sem. Fusce ullamcorper, risus at rhoncus eleifend, erat turpis<br>iaculis erat, vitae luctus dolor nisl sed mi. Maecenas cursus et lectus<br>sit amet cursus.</p></div></div>
        </div>
        <div id="area_13" style="position:absolute; left:32px; top:684px; width:951px; height:15px;"> <img id="Landing_Template2_18" src="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/tpl/landing_page_templates/Full_Page_Template/images/Landing_Template2_18.png" width="951" height="15" alt=""> </div>
        <div id="area_14" class="dragThis" style="position: absolute; left: 212px; top: 701px; width: auto; height: auto; color: rgb(0, 91, 127); text-align: center; font-size: 40px; overflow:hidden;" data-color-default="#005b7f" data-font-default="Verdana" data-content-type="text"><div id="edit">Fill out the form below to sign up</div></div>
        <div id="area_15" class="dragThis" style="position:absolute;left:361px;top:757px;padding:20px;">
            <form method="post" id="optForm" action="https://jdvinnovations.locmktsys.com/optin.php">
                <div id="formArea" style="padding:10px;height:auto;border-radius: 5px;box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #333;background-color:#FFF;">
                    <div id="formLeft" style="float:left;padding: 10px;"> <span style="padding:5px;font-size:14px;">
                        <label for="email">Email:<br />
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="thisInput" value="">
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        </span> </div>
                    <div id="formRight" style="float:right;padding: 10px;"> </div>
                    <div id="formBottom" style="clear:both;text-align:center;">
                        <input type="submit" style="width: 75px;padding: 4px;   border: 1px solid #828282;  color: #828282;border-radius: 5px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 14px;" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="page" id="page" value="33">
                <input type="hidden" name="page_type" id="page_type" value="new">
                <input type="hidden" name="tag" id="tag" value="new_landing_page" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="area_16" style="position:absolute; left:32px; top:1109px; width:951px; height:35px;"> <img id="Landing_Template2_23" src="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/tpl/landing_page_templates/Full_Page_Template/images/Landing_Template2_23.png" width="951" height="35" alt=""> </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I then have controls on the page in another div that allow the user to change things such as the color of the text and the font size, etc..

i have removed the `.draggable('parnet')` from the code because it was messing everything up.

a single click wouldnt close the edit and if i double clicked on another edit area they would both be textareas then when i clicked away they would both inherit the same value.

Is there anything i can do or change progamming wise that would make this better?

i a semi new to jquery that is this complex (i know this isnt really complex).

anything would help.. even to point to to a tutorial or documentation.

Thank you in advnace.

I can provide access to the actual page upon request. i dont want to braodcast the link..

Comment: can anyone provide anything?

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion try looking into http://www.getuikit.com/index.html and build with that. they have a lot of great features.